# Stream video from Raspberry Pi 4 while another program uses the pi camera as well

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi 4 with a camera module on it and a pan-tilt hat.
I've made a project which when started, it uses the feed from the RPI camera, detects a face and center around it. If the person moves, the camera tracks him.

When I run the .py file through the terminal, it works.
Now I want to use it with my PC. Therefore, I need to simultaneously run my project in the background AND to steam the feed to my PC somehow.

From the methods I searched online, I saw that it's possible to use flask and get a URL to use as an IP camera.

My question is, is it possible to stream the camera feed while my projects runs and tracks the face?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you run your `.py` file with `name_of_py.py &` and background the process? Will that do what you're looking for?

Comment: @JJAsghar Well eventually when I boot the RPI I want it to automatically start the project and track faces. I found a way to stream the camera feed using flask, but it's a project on it's on, therefore it has it's own videostream and read from cv2. I need to somehow implement it into my existing project so the camera feed will be outputted to the stream, while the feed is used in other process that detect the face and all. And that's my problem.

Comment: Found a tutorial that might be useful in its client part. Will try it: https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/04/15/live-video-streaming-over-network-with-opencv-and-imagezmq/